# Scraping multiple sites in one scrapy-spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am scraping 6 sites in 6 different spiders. But now, I have to scrape these sites in one single spider. Is there a way of scraping multiple links in the same spider??

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please see 'How do I ask a good question?' here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its alright, I solved the error. I have posted my solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by

```
def start_requests(self):
  yield Request('url1',callback=self.url1)
  yield Request('url2',callback=self.url2)
  yield Request('url3',callback=self.url3)
  yield Request('url4',callback=self.url4)
  yield Request('url5',callback=self.url5)
  yield Request('url6',callback=self.url6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import spider1
import spider2
import spider3
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

if require_spider1:
  spider = spider1
  urls = ['https://site1.com/']
elif require_spider2:
  spider = spider2
  urls = ['https://site2.com/', 'https://site2-1.com/']
elif require_spider3:
  spider = spider3
  urls = ['https://site3.com']

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(spider, urls=urls)
process.start()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).